# If input is "X", multiply by "Y"

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to do a simple math operation, but I'm stuck.

Ask user to introduce an amount of money:

```
puts "Capital to deposit"
capital = gets.chomp
```

Ask user to introduce a fixed number of days:

```
puts "Indicate days of deposit"
deposit_time = gets.chomp
```

I made the following array with the only possible answers for step #2:

```
deposit_time = [30, 45, 60]
```

I need a multiplication operation that depends on what the user chooses in step #2. For instance, let's suppose the user chooses `30`. I would need the code to read:

```
capital = 10
deposit_time = 30
```

to multiply `10 * 1.0219` and print the resulting number: `10.219`. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm ashamed to say that the array field is the furthest I've been...

Comment: Just to clarify. If user chooses 30, I need to: capital * 1.0219; if user chooses 45, I need to: capital * 1.0336; if user chooses 60, I need to: capital * 1.0467 and print the resulting number for each case. Thanks.

Comment: Please read "[ask]". We'd like to see a minimal sample of your code demonstrating the problem you're seeing. Odds are extremely good your question has been answered multiple times on SO and elsewhere on the internet.

Comment: When adding clarifying information to a question, please edit the question itself (see the "edit" link) rather than adding a comment.  The question should stand on its own, without having to read the comments.

Answer (score 4):

Use a hash, not an array.

```
deposit_rates = { 30 => 1.0219, 45 => 1.0336, 60 => 1.0467 }

deposit_time = gets.to_i
deposit_rate = deposit_rates[deposit_time]
# will be `nil` if not one of the defined ones
```